# Look up in R based on variable

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and have  a basic question in R
I have a data frame as shown below.

```
df

Task  Start
ABC   1/1/2017
DEF   6/15/2017
```

I have a variable A and current value is ABC

```
A = "ABC"
```

My requirement is to lookup the value in df on Task column and retrieve "Start" value and assign it to another variable B

My desired output in this case is `B = "1/1/2017"`

Comment: This is very basic subsetting. Have you tried anything yet? What did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df$Task` should output a vector with all tasks

`df$Task=="ABC"` or `df$Task==A` should output a vector with True/False for each element in the above-mentioned vector

`df$Start[df$Task=="ABC"]` should be the element you are looking for (namely "1/1/2017"), which has been called by its position in the vector df$Start

therefore you want to do: `B=df$Start[df$Task=="ABC"]`

A possible problem can occur if you have more than 1 tasks with the very same name. Then `df$Start[df$Task=="ABC"]` will return a vector with all the start dates of all the tasks, which have that name.